# Different ways to declare variables?

Tags: c#

```
abstract class Component
{
    public abstract void Operation();
}
abstract class Decorator : Component
{
    protected Component component;

    public void SetComponent(Component component)
    {
      this.component = component;
    }
}
```

I have to above code, what is the meaning of protected Component component; I know that protected is its visibility but what about Component component, is component a variable and its datatype is Component?

Comment: Strictly speaking, `component` is a field. But yeah, it's a bit like a variable.

Comment: Really. Take a few hours to read a C# tutorial.

Comment: Hi @user3741685 if any of these answers has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

To define the following:

```
protected Component component;
```

`protected` defines the accessibility. `Component` is the data type. `component` is the name.

Comment: Can I give any data type rather then only predefined datatypes like int, string etc?

Comment: You can declare variables of any type that actually exists.  When you use a native C# data type, e.g. `int` or `string`, it will turn blue in VS because it's a language keyword.  Those native data types are all implemented using .NET types though, e.g. the `Int32` structure and the `String` class.  You can declare a variable of any type, i.e. any structure, class, enumeration, interface or delegate, at all.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is (basically): Yes.

In this case the defined variable is a field. From [Fields (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms173118.aspx):

> A field is a variable of any type that is declared directly in a class or struct.

As you already assumed the three parts mean:

- `protected` is the accessibility level. Read more in [Access Modifiers (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx)
- `Component` is the data type. Read more in [Types (C#-Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/3ewxz6et.aspx)
- `component` is the name of the variable. Read more in [Identifiers (C# Language Specification)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa664670%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

In general variables are declared like this:

```
<datatype> <name>;
```

or with an initial value:

```
<datatype> <name> = <value>;
```

For a field declaration, you obviously can specify the accessibility level:

```
<accessibility> <datatype> <name>;
<accessibility> <datatype> <name> = <value>;
```

If you don't specify the accessibility level (it's optional) your field will be private by default.

To learn all this, you should start with a [tutorial on C#](http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/basics/variables/) and on [C# Datatypes](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_data_types.htm).